# Running Python via batch, different Python.exe lovations?

Tags: python, batch-file, installation, location

I have a working Python script in daily use, created and used at the begining im Spyder.
Now I have created a bat file to run the tool.
Problem:
The tool should be used by 4 different user in daily work. Every user has done Python installation on their own. That means the locations of python.exe are different.
How to fix this issue?

Is there a way to perform a if/elif/else in the bat file based on system user?

Or is the only way to create different bat files per user?

Thanks
Nils

Answer (score 0):

As long as all system users have the path to their python binary on the **PATH** environment variable, you can use the `where` command to locate the path. (for linux/mac users there is the `which` command that works simmilar)

when I enter `where python.exe` into my command prompt it prints out a list of all python.exe's that can be found in directories in my **PATH** environment variable.

check `where /?` for more information about how the `where` command works.

So all you need to do is using the `where` command to find the python binary for the respective user and then call it with your script in your batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set "myexe=clg.bbb"
set "myexeloc="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where "%myexe%" 2^>nul') do set "myexeloc=%%a"&goto found
for %%d in (u w v c) do for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s "%%d:\%myexe%" 2^>nul') do set "myexeloc=%%a"&goto found

echo "%myexe%" Not found
goto :eof

:found
echo myexeloc=%myexeloc%

GOTO :EOF
```

You'd need to set `myexe` to your required executable-name. My setting suits my testing (batch looks for any file, not just executables.)

The first `for` searches the `path` as described by @bckmnn and on the first returned value, sets `myexeloc` and reports the find.

The `2>nul` suppresses error messages.

If the search is unsuccessful, the list of drives given to `%%d` is searched, in the sequence given, for the file. The setting I used is a mixture of drives that exist and don't exist on my machine. You could use the full alphabet if you like, but the search process is likely to be time-consuming. The most-likely drivenames should thus be specified first in the space-separated list.